# Как перекодировать строку в байты в кодировки ANSI?

Tags: c#, delphi, ansi

есть строка из delphi:

```
TEncoding.ANSI.GetBytes(Text)
```

и мне надо перенести её в C#.

и как понимаю эта перекодировка в байты в кодировки ANSI,
но в C# в Encoding не вижу ANSI кодировки

Comment: `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text)`

Comment: В Делфи есть еще пара функций Ord() и Chr()  (работают с отдельными символами, не со строками).